# Nested Double curly braces in jinja2 templates

Tags: python-3.x, templates, jinja2

How do I make the result of one expression evaluate to another in jinja2 templates?
Something like:

```
{% for category in categories %}
  <p>{{ category.{{ category.pk }} }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

where category is a class object
to evaluate to

```
<p>{{ category.news }}</p>
```

and then that to evaluate to something else like

```
<p>[list, of, items]</p>
```

Comment: Why dont you try this:  {% for category in categories %}
  <p>{{ category.[category.pk] }}</p>
{% endfor %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using `[]` in place of **.** as shown below

```
{% for category in categories %}
  <p>{{ category[category.pk] }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

**Hint:** given by [Abhishek Kulkarni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11362370/abhishek-kulkarni)

this is because you can use `.` or `[]` to get a class attribute as pointed out in the [Jinja docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#variables)